# facebook like button: change width and height

Tags: php, facebook-like, width

I have a plugin where is displayed some news with a like facebook button.
I would change the width of this like in this site:
(see the right sidebar)
http://www.fanpage.it/moody-s-boccia-anche-la-germania-e-la-prima-volta-per-la-merkel/

This is my site:
http://www.clouderize.it/michele/

For my button I use this url but whatever width value I set, the button dimension not change!
How can I do ?

```
<iframe 
        src="http://www.facebook.com/widgets/like.php?href=<? the_permalink(); ?>&layout=button_count&width=450&action=like&colorscheme=light&font&show_faces=false&height=64"
                            scrolling="no" frameborder="0" 
                            style="border:none;">
</iframe>
```

Comment: Probably duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348235/how-can-i-make-the-facebook-like-buttons-width-automatically-resize and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9581547/change-the-width-of-the-facebook-like-button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
#fb-bar iframe{min-height:80px !important;}


<div id="fb-bar">
  <fb:like href="link"></fb:like>
</div>
```

Or

```
<div id="fb-bar">
<iframe 
        src="http://www.facebook.com/widgets/like.php?href=<? the_permalink(); ?>&layout=button_count&width=450&action=like&colorscheme=light&font&show_faces=false&height=64"
                            scrolling="no" frameborder="0" 
                            style="border:none;">
</iframe>
</div>
```